Linear modeling issue using Scipy
I am trying to design a linear model with three features: the weekly prices of three different elements. And I need to combine these prices to get the cheapest combination for each week.
I used Scipy, and when I put my data, I only had NaN at the end, and I don't understand why.
Here is what I tried:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

wprices = np.array([205.5,215,225])
cprices = np.array([216.5,214,219])
bprices = np.array([184.5,192,202])

# Minimum percentage limits for each product
wprice_min_percentage = 0.25
cprice_min_percentage = 0.25
bprice_min_percentage = 0.25

# Number of weeks
num_weeks = len(wprices)

# Objective function coefficients (negative as we want to minimize the cost)
c = np.array([-wprices, -cprices, -bprices]).T

# Constraint matrix
A = np.array([[1, 1, 1]])

# Lower bounds for the constraints
b = np.array([1])  # Total percentage should be 1 (100%)

# Upper bounds for the constraints
A_ub = np.array([[-wprice_min_percentage, -cprice_min_percentage, -bprice_min_percentage]])
b_ub = np.array([-1])  # Each product's percentage should be greater than or equal to the minimum

# Solve the linear programming problem for each week
optimal_percentages = []
for week in range(num_weeks):
    result = linprog(c[week], A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub, A_eq=A, b_eq=b)
    if result.success:
        optimal_percentages.append(result.x * 100)
    else:
        optimal_percentages.append([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])


Here's how I would solve this problem.
The first thing I want to know is why result.success is False. For that reason, I am going to print out the result object.
for week in range(num_weeks):
    result = linprog(c[week], A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub, A_eq=A, b_eq=b)
    print(result)

This results in the following output:
       message: The problem is infeasible. (HiGHS Status 8: model_status is Infeasible; primal_status is At lower/fixed bound)
       success: False
        status: 2
           fun: None
             x: None
           nit: 0
         lower:  residual: None
                marginals: None
         upper:  residual: None
                marginals: None
         eqlin:  residual: None
                marginals: None
       ineqlin:  residual: None
                marginals: None

This means that some of our constraints are contradictory. Let's look really closely at our constraints.
The first thing I notice is this:
# Lower bounds for the constraints
b = np.array([1])  # Total percentage should be 1 (100%)
# [...]
result = linprog(c[week], A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub, A_eq=A, b_eq=b)

The comment says that b is used as a lower bound. However, it is being passed as an equality constraint on the A matrix. I would suggest fixing this comment.
The next thing I looked at is our inequality constraints:
A_ub = np.array([[-wprice_min_percentage, -cprice_min_percentage, -bprice_min_percentage]])
b_ub = np.array([-1])  # Each product's percentage should be greater than or equal to the minimum
# [...]
result = linprog(c[week], A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub, A_eq=A, b_eq=b)

Let's re-write this as a mathematical equation to get a better sense for what's going on:
-wprice_min_percentage * x[0] + -cprice_min_percentage * x[1] + -bprice_min_percentage * x[2] <= -1

Let's simplify this equation:
wprice_min_percentage * x[0] + cprice_min_percentage * x[1] + bprice_min_percentage * x[2] >= 1

This shows us a mismatch between what the comments say this is doing, and what the code is really doing. The comment says that it constrains each product individually. However, this is expressing a constraint on the sum of all elements.
The second issue is that the min_percentage variable is on the wrong side of this equation.
Let's plug in some example values into this equation to show why.
wprice_min_percentage * x[0] + cprice_min_percentage * x[1] + bprice_min_percentage * x[2] >= 1
# Replace min_percentage with 0.25
0.25 * x[0] + 0.25 * x[1] + 0.25 * x[2] >= 1
# Replace x values with 0.33
0.25 * 0.33 + 0.25 * 0.33 + 0.25 * 0.33 >= 1
# Simplify
0.2475 >= 1

To fix this, I would suggest replacing A_ub and b_ub with the following:
A_ub = np.diag([-1, -1, -1])
b_ub = np.array([-wprice_min_percentage, -cprice_min_percentage, -bprice_min_percentage])  # Each product's percentage should be greater than or equal to the minimum

(Side note: the bounds argument to linprog() can also be used here, and it's easier to use.)
Let's try re-running the code, and see what we get.
>>> print(optimal_percentages)
[array([25., 50., 25.]), array([50., 25., 25.]), array([50., 25., 25.])]

It's buying as much as it can of one resource, and as little as it can of all others. If the goal is to minimize cost, then that looks plausible. Let's look at both costs and percentages at the same time.
for week in range(num_weeks):
    print("week", week)
    print(optimal_percentages[week], c[week])

Output:
week 0
[25. 50. 25.] [-205.5 -216.5 -184.5]
week 1
[50. 25. 25.] [-215. -214. -192.]
week 2
[50. 25. 25.] [-225. -219. -202.]

It seems to be buying the most expensive choice in every week. To find why, let's look at the comment at the top:
# Objective function coefficients (negative as we want to minimize the cost)
c = np.array([-wprices, -cprices, -bprices]).T

Compare that to the documentation:

Linear programming: minimize a linear objective function subject to linear equality and inequality constraints.

In other words, linprog already minimizes the objective function. If we add a negative sign, it starts maximizing the price.
The fix is to remove the negative signs:
# Objective function coefficients
c = np.array([wprices, cprices, bprices]).T

Final, full code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

wprices = np.array([205.5,215,225])
cprices = np.array([216.5,214,219])
bprices = np.array([184.5,192,202])

# Minimum percentage limits for each product
wprice_min_percentage = 0.25
cprice_min_percentage = 0.25
bprice_min_percentage = 0.25

# Number of weeks
num_weeks = len(wprices)

# Objective function coefficients
c = np.array([wprices, cprices, bprices]).T

# Constraint matrix
A = np.array([[1, 1, 1]])

# Equality constraints for A
b = np.array([1])  # Total percentage should be 1 (100%)

# Upper bounds for the constraints
A_ub = np.diag([-1, -1, -1])
b_ub = np.array([-wprice_min_percentage, -cprice_min_percentage, -bprice_min_percentage])  # Each product's percentage should be greater than or equal to the minimum

# Solve the linear programming problem for each week
optimal_percentages = []
for week in range(num_weeks):
    result = linprog(c[week], A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub, A_eq=A, b_eq=b)
    if result.success:
        optimal_percentages.append(result.x * 100)
    else:
        optimal_percentages.append([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])
for week in range(num_weeks):
    print("week", week)
    print(optimal_percentages[week], c[week])

